# How to import SAS Programs into SAS Add-In for Microsoft Office through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I made several attempts to call SAS Programs/Projects through Excel VBA: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Integration-with-Microsoft/Execute-Excel-VBA-Macro-using-SAS/m-p/450918 but none of them worked for me somehow. Some say it is because I don't have admin privileges to acess and other reasons.

Now I am trying to explore ways to import the SAS Programs into SAS Add-In. I can do them manually and record the macro. However, the excel macro doesn't record importing or running the program. I tried searching the internet but everything only explains the manual approach. Can I get some guidance on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to call SAS from VBA (if you have SSO) is via the Stored Process Server.  A guide for this is available [here](https://www.rawsas.com/2016/11/sas-as-a-service-an-easy-way-to-get-sas-into-excel-power-bi-and-000s-of-other-tools-languages/), and essentially involves refreshing web queries within excel.